# android: TextView with rounded background with dynamic background color

Tags: android

I need to make TextView with rounded background with dynamic color.
I know how to make drawable background but I don't know how to change the color of it in the code?

the drawable bg xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"></solid>
            <corners android:radius="7dp"></corners>
        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

the textview in the layout xml:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_taskTag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_solid"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:text="عمل"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
```

in the Java file code:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {  

       holder.txt_taskCategory.setText(holder.mTask._catName);
       holder.txt_taskCategory.setBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( holder.mTask._catColor));
    //when i do that it remove the drawable background and just color it.


}
```

What i need is to change the color of the drawable background (not the Textview) whith `"holder.mTask._catColor"`

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me

```
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourViewBackground);
    drawable.mutate().setColorFilter(your_resolved_color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    yourView.setBackground(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

try this (where 0xFF00FF00 is color code) to change color in java code with the condition in which you want to change it
if you want to change after some time you can set timer or use gif

Comment: i tried that before, it remove the drawable background then change the color of the view ( without the drawable background) .

Comment: you want drawable background as well as background color? how it is possible for two things to come together at one place at same time

Comment: i just need to change the color of drawable shape in the drawable background (xml) by the code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with ***RoundRectShape***. Here the example.

```
val outerRadius = floatArrayOf(20f, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f)// All corners with a radius of 20dp
val drawable = ShapeDrawable(RoundRectShape(outerRadii, null, null))
drawable.paint.color = requireContext().getColor(color)
textview.background = drawable
```